# Mysql connection timeout (JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, connection-timeout

I'm unable to start a service that uses mysql due to some connection issue. Below is the stacktrace for the same -

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.\n\tat sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor68.newInstance(Unknown Source)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:958)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2149)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2074)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:794)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44)\n\tat sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor66.newInstance(Unknown Source)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)\n\tat com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)\n\tat com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)\n\tat com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)\n\tat com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)\n\tat com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)\n\tat com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)\n\tat com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)\n\tat com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)\n\tat com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2989)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1873)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1802)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2239)\n\tat com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2090)\n\t... 18 common frames omitted\n"

Respective entries in application.properties file is -

```
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/localdb?autoReconnect=true
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=testpd
hibernate.showSql=true
hibernate.formatSql=true
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=200
hibernate.c3p0.checkout.timeout.config=10000
```

Comment: What MySQL connector are you using? Try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382824/mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-could-not-create-connection-to-database-ser).

Comment: Thanks for your response,now getting a different set of exceptions:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChains' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': 
contd...

Comment: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#65' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [65]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#65': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#733' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter] while setting constructor argument with key;nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`

Comment: You are using a too old version of MySQL Connector/J while attempting to connect to MySQL 8. Upgrade to MySQL Connector/J 8.0.x, or at minimum to 5.1.46 or higher. Your question is a duplicate of [Java: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177907/java-com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-coul)

Comment: As an aside, this is not a timeout (as you seem to think given your question title).